# Wordpress child theme causes padding changes without modifications

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, padding

[Stewartside](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2889988/stewartside) helped me use JQuery to create a specific function for my main navigation on my website (thanks again!). I created a child theme to add the changes to my header.php file and it has started to cause a weird layout change. My homepage should have 20px padding, which is NOT a special CSS modification, but the child theme automatically removes it. This doesn't happen with other pages on my site, just the homepage. I have also added/removed the jquery code to make sure that wasn't the problem; the style.css file for the child theme only has the "child theme" coding, no modified CSS.

Homepage: http://bostonirishclothing.com
About Us: http://bostonirishclothing.com/about-us

Is there anything that would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Get the Firebug add on for your browser (available on Chrome and Firefox). Then right click the section that is causing the issue and you can see the coding and all the relevant CSS functions including the files they are in (to the chosen section). It will also show which CSS function is being prioritised compared to the other. Then you can modify the functions or add new ones to make it work.

A dirty way to do things is to use `!important` however this should only be used sparingly as it can screw with other pages. An easy way to avoid that is to make the CSS function for example `.entry-content { color:#fff; }` becomes `.post-x .entry-content { color:fff!important; }`

Test things out. Firebug is amazing help when editing CSS. You can even do some of the tests in firebug itself.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I have been using Chrome's "inspect element" tool, but I'll give Firebug Lite a shot. So far I haven't been able to find anything wrong; I am wondering if I need to put a specific PHP or JS file in the child theme. So far all I have in the child theme is style.css and header.php.

Comment: I've added some left and right padding, which is giving me the look I want. I still think it is kind of wonky that I've needed to add the code though.

Comment: Something was probably conflicting with the particular css functions. Is it wonky as it not working properly or as in you feel it is a dirty way to do it?

Comment: Sorry, my use of the term "wonky" was regarding to the fact that I had to add the code to my child theme for it to act like the original/parent theme.